# How can I add new parameters to this restrict function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function which restricts access to some of the places on my site. In this code, the userGroup must be 'user' for the person to get through to the links on the site. However, I have recently added the userGroup 'vip' but they cannot access the links because the parameter passed in the method is only 'user'. I'm not really sure what I have to do in order to make it work with both 'user' and 'vip'.... But here is my code:

The method `$this->access->restrict('user');` is called here:

```
class MY_User extends MY_Controller {
    function MY_User() {
        parent::MY_Controller();

        // Protect the user area
        $this->access->restrict('user');

        // Don't want to cache this content
        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    }
}
```

and gets passed to the restrict() function:

```
function restrict($userGroup = FALSE)
{

    if($userGroup == 'logged_out')
    {
        if ($this->CI->user->id > 0)
        {
            redirect('user');
        }
    }
    else if($this->CI->user->id < 0)
    {
        $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());

        redirect();
    } else if($this->CI->user->userGroup != 'admin'){
        if ($userGroup AND $this->CI->user->userGroup !== $userGroup)
        {
            $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());
            redirect();
        }
    }
}
```

I realize I must create a new parameter in

```
 function restrict($userGroup = FALSE)
```

and

```
$this->access->restrict('user');
```

but I am not sure what to do after that

Comment: "Accept" the answer which works for you. Don't use the `[Resolved]` in the title.

Comment: Not yet, but you will be able to after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

I changed:

```
else if($this->CI->user->userGroup != 'admin'){
    if ($userGroup AND $this->CI->user->userGroup !== $userGroup)
    {
        $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());
        redirect();
    }
}
```

to:

```
    else if($this->CI->user->userGroup != 'admin'){
        if($this->CI->user->userGroup != 'vip'){
            if ($userGroup AND $this->CI->user->userGroup !== $userGroup)
            {
                $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());
                redirect();
            }
        }
    }
```

And a second solution that works (thank you nickb:

```
function restrict($userGroup = FALSE)
{

  if( $this->CI->user->id < 0)
{
    $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());
    return redirect();
}

if($userGroup == 'logged_out')
{
    if ($this->CI->user->id > 0)
    {
        redirect('user');
    }
}

switch($this->CI->user->userGroup)
{
    case 'vip':
    break;
    case 'user':
    break;
    case 'admin':
    break;
    default:
        $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());
            return redirect();
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume a call to `redirect` means you want the function to end there, so I've returned redirect (unless for some other reason calling redirect causes the function to terminate, then remove `return`).

```
function restrict($userGroup = FALSE)
{
    if( $this->CI->user->id < 0)
    {
        $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());
        return redirect();
    }

    switch( $userGroup)
    {
        case 'logged_out':
            if( $this->CI->user->id > 0)
            {
                return redirect( 'user');
            }
        break;
        case 'vip':
        case 'user':
            if( !( $this->CI->user->userGroup == $userGroup))
            {
                $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('referrer', $this->CI->uri->uri_string());
                return redirect();
            }
        break;
        case 'admin':
            // Something - Maybe don't do anything?
        break;
        default:
            // Something ?
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you. I just found a solution myself but I will look into yours as well. I posted my solution down below

Comment: If you add more user groups your code will become harder and harder to manage - A `switch` statement is a fluid and clear way to do something based on a finite set of possibilities.